# How to use threading to play an audio in Raspberry pi using python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, python-multithreading

I am new to python. I am trying to write a program which will keep playing the audio when the GPIO 21 pin LED turns on. I want the complete audio file to be played and not for just 2 seconds. Whenever the LED turns on the file should start playing(Note: it should not interrupt if the audio is already playing). I couldn't figure out how threading works in my situation. Now the audio plays for 2 sec and stops

```
import threading
import pygame
import time
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(21,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(20,GPIO.OUT)
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

ring = pygame.mixer.Sound("odo.wav")

def audio_play():
    global pygame
    ring.play()
    sleep(5)

def led():
    while(1):
        GPIO.output(21,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(20,GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(10)
        GPIO.output(21,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(20,GPIO.HIGH)
        try:
            audio.start()
        except RuntimeError:
            audio = threading.Thread(target=audio_play)
            audio.start()
        time.sleep(10)

led=threading.Thread(target=led)
audio=threading.Thread(target=audio_play)

led.start()

led.join()
audio.join()
```

Comment: Remove the `ring.stop()`?

Comment: That worked as expected. can't we use audio.start() inside a loop. It is throwing an error "RuntimeError: threads can only be started once"

Comment: You have to create a new thread.

Comment: @KlausD. The audio plays continuously once it is started. How can I know the audio is completed? I want to add    `ring.stop()` once the audio completes

Comment: This is the second time you have extended your question beyond the original scope.

Comment: Sorry for that, I will check for the solution. If I can't find I will add a new question